# Import IP Address in my Javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have to get the value from my database in order to draw a chart. But i want to connect to the database whatever my ip address is. My database data are coming via a php file : productivity1.php

Here is a sample of my JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
    url : "http://172.20.10.9/www/productivity1.php",
    type : "GET",

    [...]

});
```

So my question is, how can i find my IP address and put it into the url :"..."

Can i use the php file?

```
<?php
$localIP = getHostByName(getHostName());
echo $localIP ;
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `localhost` ?

Comment: Because i have some devices which are sendind data to my database via my IP address

Comment: Do you mean whatever the Clients IP Address is, or do you mean that your server ip address will change??

Comment: `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` but it's not 100% reliable

Comment: window.location.hostname

Comment: I mean whatever the server ip address

Comment: Server ip addresses normally dont change. If your server address ip may change then you may need to look at setting up a Dynamic DNS (DYNDNS.COM). That way the domain name does not change and thats what your code would use. A little bit of software runs on the server which updates the dynamic dns whenever the servers ip changes

Comment: I agree, normally it wont change. Thanks for your advise, i'm gonna look into your software.